# Return an array of uniq keys from a query of hstore data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I would like to use hstore keys as table column headers.  My approach is to simply map a rails query that will return all keys from multiple records and then print the uniq ones to the array.

I'll be building the table in Prawn, using both static and dynamic column headers...like this..but, this doesnt work of course.

```
 [["DATE", "LOCATION", "DAY OFF", "START", "END" + @users_options.select("properties").map { |k,v| ",#{k}" }]]
```

How can I iterate over the users logs, and output only uniq keys?

I just tried this...seems close...but not working yet

```
 a = []
 user.useroptions.select(:properties).collect{ |k,v| a << k }
```

Comment: Its easy to get the keys from one record @users_options.keys....but, getting the keys from multiple records is not so easy.

Comment: One thing I could do...is simple loop through the records and combine all the hstore hashes in to one hash...not sure how to do this without being destructive.  Then, get the uniq keys from the one hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a helper method:

```
def keys(user)
  keys = []
  user.useroptions.select(:properties).each do |opt| 
    a = opt.properties.keys
    keys << a
  end

  keys.flatten.uniq
end
```

This iterates through all hstore records, grabs the keys, then flattens the hash, and puts only the uniq values

Comment: Now, the problem I am having is the returned values of keys is an array.  I need to somehow embed this array in with the static values that are already in the static array...without breaking the array..

Answer (score 0):

To finish this off, I moved the static array items into the helper and used the 'unshift' method...so that I spit out one array to the Prawn table builder.

```
def keys(user)
  keys = []
  user.useroptions.select(:properties).each do |opt| 
    a = opt.properties.keys
    keys << a
 end

 keys.flatten.uniq
```

end

```
keys.flatten.uniq.unshift("DATE", "LOCATION", "DAY OFF", "START", "END")
```

then I slip my helper in to the Prawn table

```
    [keys(@users_logs)] +

    ....table rows
```